# ModuleNotFoundError: using Spyder

Tags: module, spyder

6 Hours into trying to fix this i gave up.

Im just trying to import basic moduls that are installed on my MAC, i can run bs4, pandas etc etc on sublime, jupyter etc except SPYDER. The console outputs the following

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-50b2309bcaa6>", line 1, in <module>
    import bs4

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Things i have tried.

I changed the Nano file on mac so that Python = 'python3' and pip = 'pip3': Didn't work.

Changing the IPython console settings to Run a module: Worked for the module Request but the the other modules still fail (bs4,pandas,etcetc)

Restarting my computer 100 times: Didn't work

Googeling the shit out of it: Didn't work

Uppercutting the MAC: Didn't work

Comment: i think that after changing the nano file i f**** up my jupyter notebook. Bcs it wont start...

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please see the second part of [our video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs) to understand how to work with environments and connect them to Spyder. That's what you need to install your package.